# numpy.sum performance depending on axis

Tags: python, performance, numpy

When summing over a dimension in a numpy array, is there a performance difference between the first and the last axis?

Specifically, considering the following code, which of `sum1` and `sum2` will be performed faster?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((1000,200))
b = np.ones((200,1000))
sum1 = np.sum(a, axis=0)
sum2 = np.sum(b, axis=-1)
```

I believe this question actually boils down to how does numpy internally store dimensions and that this can be overriden to use row-wise or column-wise format. However, when using the default setting, which of these will be faster? Also, what about N-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is quite easy to check whether or not there is a performance difference (IPython, I increased a bit the numbers to have a more noticeable difference):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((10000, 2000))
b = np.ones((2000, 10000))
%timeit np.sum(a, axis=0)
# 27.6 ms ± 541 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit  np.sum(b, axis=-1)
# 34.6 ms ± 876 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Now, by the time you are having an actual performance issue with `np.sum` you will probably have run out of memory anyway, but yes, there is a difference. By default, NumPy arrays are stored in [row-major order](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-row-major), so first goes the first row, then the second, etc. It does make sense, then, that summing (or operating) in outer dimensions is faster, because the cache will be way more effective. Simply puy, in the first case, when you get the first element of the array a bunch of contiguous data will come to the cache with it, so when you want to sum the next elements they will be already there. In the second case, on the other hand, elements to sum are quite far away from each other (2000 elements of distance, actually), so the cache won't be helping much, column-wise. That is not to say the cache won't help at all, since you are summing all the columns, so cached data will still be reused to a degree, but not as effectively. This is a rather gross approximation, in general there are several cache levels, some shared among cores and some not, and understanding the exact effect that one or another code has on it is a complicated topic, but the general idea holds.

Comment: Are you sure about your running times? I obtain the contrary and it seems more logical because with b, each value of the output will be the sum of adjacent memory cells, hence it will be very cache efficient.

Comment: @Labo I have just run again the same snippet in a different computer (NumPy 1.14.0 with MKL, Python 3.6.4 Anaconda, Win10, Core i7-6700HQ) and I obtain similar results to what I posted, but, although I don't remember the moment I posted this, I think my reasoning may indeed be inverted. However, I wonder how NumPy actually performs this sum. If, for the first case (`a`), I take the first whole row, then I add to it the second row, then the third row, etc, that is actually cache-efficient. If I compute the first final element, then the second, etc, then it is not, though.

Comment: This can be clearly seen when summing over a single row or column -> 3 µs vs 30 µs. See https://ipython-books.github.io/45-understanding-the-internals-of-numpy-to-avoid-unnecessary-array-copying/ at the very end.