# Why does numpy.sum perform faster when axis=0 for matrix stored in row-major order?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

According to the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685406/numpy-sum-performance-depending-on-axis) post, a `numpy` array is by default stored in row-major order. The answer then said the reason that `np.sum(axis=0)` (compute sum of each column) tends to be faster than `np.sum(axis=1)` (compute sum of each row) in the case of row-major order is because memory is stored row-wise and accessing an element will cache the neighboring elements. However, this is actually contradictory to the fact that `np.sum(axis=0)` is faster!

For example, for

```
A= np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
```

when `1` is accessed, `2` and `3`, let's say, might be cached in the case of row-major order. Then it should be faster to find `1+2+3` than `1+4+7`, i.e., `np.sum(A, axis=1)` should be faster. Isn't it?

---

So what's the real explanation here?

Comment: That's too small of an example.  I don't get significant `timeit` differences.  For a much larger array, axis=1 is about 10% faster.

Comment: How large have you tried? @hpaulj

Comment: @hpaulj You're right! I tested on a cloud machine using `np.random.randn(N, N)`, it looks like when N is in the scale of a few thousands, the performance are not significantly different or `np.sum(axis=0)` is even faster. But after I scaled up N to a few $10^4$, np.sum(axis=1) is almost always faster. Now, I think the only question here is why for small array, `np.sum(axis=0)` is more likely to be faster? Basically the same question asked by the OP in the comment section in my referenced post.